# Netsuite: Is it possible to pass array in custparam?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

```
var stAccNum = '1013320075';
var stAccName = 'ABC SINGAPORE PTE LTD';

var arrRecItem = new Array();
for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    arrRecItem[x] = [];
}
;
arrRecItem[0][0] = '2';
arrRecItem[0][1] = 'DBSSSGSGXXX';
arrRecItem[0][2] = '301234567';

var arrParams = {
    custparam_jason_my_acc_num : stAccNum,
    custparam_jason_my_acc_name : stAccName,
    ***custparam_jason_rec_item_arr :  arrRecItem*** };

nlapiSetRedirectURL('SUITELET', 'customscript_jason_ss_bulk_payment_file',
        'customdeploy_jason_ss_bulk_payment_file', null, arrParams);
```

As shown in code above, I failed to pass the array arrRecItem in arrParams. Is there any ways to pass this array as custparam and pass to suitelet? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use JSON.stringify(arrRecItem) and then parse it on the suitelet with JSON.parse(arrRecItem)